# Generate wrong outgoing url because of segment variable reuse in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Here is my `RouteConfig.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
                        "{controller}/Page{page}",
                        new {controller = "Product", action = "Index", category = (string) null},
                        new {page = @"\d+"}
            );

        routes.MapRoute(null,
                        "{controller}/{category}",
                        new {controller = "Product", action = "Index", page = 1}
            );

        routes.MapRoute(null,
                        "{controller}/{category}/Page{page}",
                        new {controller = "Product", action = "Index"},
                        new {page = @"\d+"}
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And here is the code for generating url:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Cart", "Index", "ShoppingCart", null, new { @class = "btn btn-orange" })
```

It works well when I navigate to, for example, `Product/Page2`, `Product/Laptop`, `Product/Laptop/Page2`. The problem is, whenever my current URL contains `Page` segment, it will try to reuse that segment for generating outgoing URL. So, if I'm at `Product/Page2` the above generated URL would be `ShoppingCart/Page2`. I don't know how to avoid this.

Please help me. Thank you so much.

**EDIT!!!**

I've found a workaround way. Instead of using `ActionLink`, I use `RouteLink` like this:

```
@Html.RouteLink("View Cart", "Default", new { controller = "ShoppingCart", action = "Index" }, new { @class = "btn btn-orange" })
```

But I still want to use `ActionLink`, so please help me.

**EDIT!!!**

The workaround way doesn't work when I generate a link to `ShoppingCart/Checkout`. It still take me to `Index` action in `ShoppingCart` controller.

Comment: For the shopping cart link, which route are you targeting?

Comment: The last one, just the normal pattern, controller/action.

Comment: but it matches in the second route itself. You need to narrow the second mapping with more constraints or rearrange the mappings and see if it helps.

Comment: What should I do now? The second one is for the category of the product. When I change all `{controller}` into `Product`, everything works perfectly. Is that the solution?

Comment: If that route target only the `Product` Controller, that is the way to go.

Comment: In my situation, I just target `Product` controller. But I wonder if I target other controllers, what should I do?

Comment: Mapping same number of parameters is a pain. You'll need to either make `Id` mandatory in the last route or use id parameter as the page and get rid of the second mapping altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new route pattern specific to ShoppingCart and make it the first route by **placing it at the TOP**.

```
    routes.MapRoute(null,
                    "ShoppingCart/{action}",
                    new {controller = "Product"});
        );
```

As a rule all the specific routes should come first.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way the routing system tries to evaluate the value of segment variables when trying to match against a route.

So when the call to render the link occurs with the following arguments:

`@Html.ActionLink("View Cart", "Index", "ShoppingCart", null, new { @class = "btn btn-orange" })`

the framework when evaluating the route with template

`{controller}/Page{page}`

will resolve the `controller` segment variable to be `ShoppingCart` however when it cannot find a value for the `page` segment variable (via any of the arguments in the method call), it will then try and resolve that value from the RouteData object in the ViewContext. Since you have navigated to `Product/Page2`, the current value of `page` within the routes value dictionary is `2`.

You can inspect this by looking at the value of `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["page"]` when rendering that view.